# Nested Parameters in Informatica

Tags: shell, parameter-passing, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I want to see number of affected rows of my target table. For that, I can write a shell script in which I pass a parameter as $PM@numAffectedRows. However, if my target table name is parameterized and I want to pass that in the same shell, how can I do that?

Eg.
$ParamTgtTable=myTable
When I pass $PM'$ParamTgtTable'@numAffectedRows in the shell script, it echos myTable@numAffectedRows. If I pass the same without the quote as $PM$ParamTgtTable@numAffectedRows, I get $ParamTgtTable@numAffectedRows as my output.

Is there any workaround for this? Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I think you need to use $PMTargetName@numAffectedRow, where TargetName is exactly what it says: name of the Target Definition (transformation), not the underlying DB table name. Please verify and let me know if I'm wrong or misunderstood sometihng.

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but if I have target name parameterized, how can I pass the parameter inside the parameter?

Comment: I believe there's a small misunderstanding. As per my understanding, the 'parametrized target name' you've mentiond refers to 'Target Table' property on Target Transformation. What you need to use is the latter: name of the Target Transformation. This is something where parameters are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

pass 2 parameters seperately like 
$ParamTgtTable=myTable
$PM@numAffectedRows=your_count

now create a third parameter as X=$ParamTgtTable$PM@numAffectedRows
if didnt work try using single quotes (i dont have access to UNIX to test right now)